# Formatting (Indentation) of SQL Query in Snowflake SQL Editor

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do anybody knows the way or short cut keys to format any long SQL query written in Snowflake editor. 
I have gone through the whole Snowflake documentation, but couldn't find any.

Comment: Have you checked out https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html#formatting-queries-using-keyboard-shortcuts? Several of the third party SQL clients that connect with Snowflake, like DBeaver, also support shortcuts: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Shortcuts

Comment: I just use Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter in notepad++

Comment: Thanks @kevins_1, I have downloaded DBeaver, its working fine.

Comment: Thanks @SimeonPilgrim for telling me about this tool, it will help me a lot in other tasks as well.

Comment: nothing i can find there. consider Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter in notepad++,  dbeaver / datagrip by jetbrains... im sure there are other options.

Comment: Yes, I also unable to find anything there, so I am now using other formatters availbale. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Snowflake Web GUI, there are only some basic keyboard shortcuts (-> [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html#formatting-queries-using-keyboard-shortcuts)):
`TAB` and `Ctrl-[` + `Ctrl-]` to indent/outdent parens levels.

Also navigation and search/replace.
But no complete expression formatting, alas.

We can only hope for the [Numeracy acquisition](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/numeracy-investing-in-our-query-ui/)  to give us a fuller database web client, eventually.